# onsubmit function used for form is coming up undefined

Tags: javascript, html, forms, function, onsubmit

I want to validate my form, and have created a formValidation function with onsubmit, that calls a function from a js.js file. When I click submit, however, I get this error:

[image]

Here is the necessary form code:

```
 <form action="send-email.php" id="callback" class="popup-form" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
 // Form content
</form>
```

Here is the function code:

```
function validateForm() {
  console.log("hellloooooo this is working");
//   var captcha_response = grecaptcha.getResponse();
//   if(captcha_response.length === 0)
//   {
//       // Captcha is not Passed
//       console.log("not working");
//       return false;
//   }
//   else
//   {
//       // Captcha is Passed
//       console.log("working");
//       return true;
//   }
}
```

The script tag is within the body tag, so it should work.. where am I going wrong??

Comment: Please post your complete HTML code.

Comment: Online handlers can find only global functions.

Comment: @Teemu right, my bad ... removed.

Answer (score 1):

Please use input type='submit' in form. It will work in java script as well.

Add submit input in the form as below

```
<form action="send-email.php" id="callback" class="popup-form" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()"><input type="submit">
</form>
```

And in java script write your validation function as below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function validateForm(){
    console.log('ddd');
    return false;
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be sure that your  script tag  above your form tag

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be working. Don't see any issue here

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>

</head>

<body>
    <script>
        function validateForm() {
            console.log("hellloooooo this is working");
        }
    </script>
    <form id="callback" class="popup-form" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
        // Form content
        <input type="Submit">
    </form>

</body>

</html>
```